Dark mode change not working, predefined text is same color as background
So basically I tried to add a dark mode feature to my app with provider, on the main page everything is fine, but when I change to dark mode my title changes to the same color as my background. Why is that? Changing it back to light mode shows the same outcome, the titleText is the same as the background.
    class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDarkMode = false;

  void toggleTheme() {
    isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
    print('Theme toggled: isDarkMode = $isDarkMode');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ThemeData get themeData => isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

}


ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0,
  ) ,
  textTheme: TextTheme(
  titleLarge: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.black, 
  ),
),
);


ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.teal,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.teal,
    elevation: 0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
  titleLarge: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 25,
    color: Colors.white, 
  ),
)
);

The main.dart file:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
      child: const MainApp(),
    ),);
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: themeProvider.themeData,
        home: const IntroPage());
  }
}

And I use it like this:
Text(
                  introPages[index]["title"]!,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge, 
                ),


I tested your code when I choose the dark mode the text color was white and in light mode it was black , I guess there is miss understanding , something else you are looking for , what do need to do , let me know what you are looking for exactly

I think it's theme is not properly rebuilding Please refer below code I hope it's useful
Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
    child: const MainApp(),
  ));
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
      builder: (context, themeProvider, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: themeProvider.themeData,
          home: const IntroPage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              introPages[index]["title"]??"",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false).toggleTheme();
              },
              child: const Text('Toggle Theme'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDarkMode = false;

  void toggleTheme() {
    isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ThemeData get themeData => isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme;
}

ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    titleLarge: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
);

ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.teal,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
    color: Colors.teal,
    elevation: 0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    titleLarge: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);


Please explain how this actually solves the issue. What have you've changed to address the issue? Code-only answers are not good answers.

code is almost correct i just give proper code with theme ontap so if any issue with ontap so it's useful otherwise code is almost right

Please [edit] the answer and add all details inside - Please explain how this is the "proper" way. Adding references/documentation is always a plus.
